# one group pre/post test

Tags: t-test, paired-data, intervention-analysis

I am conducting a one-group pre-intervention / post-intervention test. All the subjects completed the intervention as otherwise there would be ethical concerns. Is there any test other than a paired t-test that can be used to also take into account covariates, such as time, experience, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with any alternative but there are also problems with the paired t in this situation.

But one thing you could do is look at whether score (or result or whatever) is related to whatever it is you are interested in and add pre- vs. post- as a variable.

One problem is that, unless the measure is close to perfect, you could be testing the error rather than the effect of the intervention.